# What is the least and greatest element in symmetric but not reflexive relation over $\{1,2,3\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

> Let $S=\{1,2,3\}$ and $R$ be a symmetric but not reflexive relation over $S$. Because $R$ is a set of all relations (under the given conditions) over $S$ then $\subseteq$ is a partial order over $R$. Prove that there's the least element in $R$ and prove that $R$ doesn't have the greatest element.

I think that the empty set is the least element in $R$ because for empty set is in any subset of $R$ by definition of empty set. Therefore the empty set is in relation with every element of $R$.

I'm confused why $R$ doesn't have the greatest element. Isn't it:
$$
X=\{(1,2),(2,1),(1,3),(3,1),(2,3),(3,2)\}
$$
?

$X$ contains all the symmetric pairs in $R$ and it contains every other element of $R$.

Comment: Small remark to enhance your question. You denote by $R$ one relation having the required properties and the set of all those relations. This is confusing.

Comment: Notice that if you add $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ to the relation that you wrote then it is still symmetric and not reflexive and larger. Likewise if you add $(1,1)$ and $(3,3)$. But the two relations thus formed are only contained in the $=$ relation, which is reflexive. Therefore, in $R$ there is no relation larger than those two.

Comment: I suppose that $R$ is rather the **set** of all symmetric, but not reflexie relations on $S$. Note that $\{(1,1),(2,2)\}\in R$ and $\{(3,3)\}\in R$. What does that imply for a gerates element $A$ of $R$?

Comment: I see my mistake $R$ contains pairs like $(1,1)$ but can't contain all of them. Therefore it's not in relation with every subset. But then there're many maximal elements right? The max elements will contain $X$ and four pairs of type $(x,x)$ right?

Comment: Yes, that set of relations has $3$ maximal elements, obtained by removing $(1,1)$, or $(2,2)$, or $(3,3)$ from the full relation $S\times S$ (which above I mistakenly called $=$), but no maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first create a not confusing question.

Let S = {1, 2, 3} and
K = { R subset S×S : R is symmetric and not reflexive }.
Give K the subset order.  Does K have a maximum?

A = { (1,1) } in K.  B = { (2,2) } in K.  C = { (3,3) } in K.
If K had a maximum M, then { (1,1), (2,2), (3,3) } subset M.
As M is reflexive, a contradiction ensues.